# How can I extract dup values with same max date based on another var?

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data-wrangling

I have generated 'withrepeats' a df with rows that have at least one duplicate in another df (with variable DROPS as number of repeats per unique FID+ID).

```
FID ID CID CT DROPS    DATE
123 CV  1  2    3   11-3-2020
123 CV  2  2    2   11-3-2020
123 CV  3  1    1   11-3-2020  
456 LO  1  1    2   10-4-2020 
456 LO  2  1    1   10-5-2020
678 IP  1  2    3   11-1-2020
678 IP  1  1    2   11-2-2020
678 IP  2  2    1   10-29-2020
111 AK  1  2    2   11-2-2020
111 AK  2  2    1   11-1-2020
222 PL  4  2    2   11-1-2020
222 PL  3  2    2   11-1-2020
```

I want to extract only one of the drops per unique ID and FID, keeping the latest DATE. For rows with CT == 1, I want to keep only that row and keep the latest date. For those rows with only CT== 2 values, keep the latest date, as well. This is the line of code I am using:

`keepers <- withrepeats %>% group_by %>% (ID, FID) %>% filter(DATE == max(DATE))`

However, the rows that have the same date are being kept. In this case, I would would like to keep the highest CID , or, where there is a row where CT == 1, keep that row.

Desired output:

```
FID ID CID CT DROPS    DATE
123 CV  3  1    1   11-3-2020   
456 LO  2  1    1   10-5-2020
678 IP  1  1    2   11-2-2020
111 AK  1  2    2   11-2-2020
222 PL  4  2    2   11-1-2020
```

How would you go about this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the expected output correct

Comment: I updated the df and output. thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the 'DATE' to `Date` class, then do a group by 'FID' and `slice` the row with the `max` value in 'DATE'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
withrepeats %>%
   mutate(DATE = mdy(DATE)) %>%
   arrange(FID, desc(CID)) %>%
   group_by(FID) %>% 
   mutate(mxDate = if(any(CT == 1)) DATE[which.max(DATE)] else 
        DATE[which.max(DATE)]) %>%
   filter(DATE == mxDate & !duplicated(DATE)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   slice(c(2, 4, 5, 1, 3)) %>%
   select(-mxDate)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#    FID ID      CID    CT DROPS DATE      
#  <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <date>    
#1   123 CV        3     1     1 2020-11-03
#2   456 LO        2     1     1 2020-10-05
#3   678 IP        1     1     2 2020-11-02
#4   111 AK        1     2     2 2020-11-02
#5   222 PL        4     2     2 2020-11-01
```

#### data

```
withrepeats <- structure(list(FID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 456L, 456L, 678L, 678L, 
678L, 111L, 111L, 222L, 222L), ID = c("CV", "CV", "CV", "LO", 
"LO", "IP", "IP", "IP", "AK", "AK", "PL", "PL"), CID = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), CT = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), DROPS = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), DATE = c("11-3-2020", "11-3-2020", 
"11-3-2020", "10-4-2020", "10-5-2020", "11-1-2020", "11-2-2020", 
"10-29-2020", "11-2-2020", "11-1-2020", "11-1-2020", "11-1-2020"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thank you! There are a few rows of PID+ID where there is no CT == 1, only 2. I don't want to filter those out completely, but still keep the drop with latest date for those.  I will update my datasubset. Thanks again

Comment: @akrum thank you. how do I do to keep the highest CID or CASE_ID for those that have same dates?

Answer (score 0):

First convert `DATE` to actual date objects, `arrange` data by `FID`, `ID` and `CT` values and select the max `DATE` for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

withrepeats %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, '%m-%d-%Y')) %>%
  arrange(FID, ID, CT) %>%
  group_by(FID, ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(DATE))

#    FID ID      CID    CT DROPS DATE      
#  <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <date>    
#1   111 AK        1     2     2 2020-11-02
#2   123 CV        3     1     1 2020-11-03
#3   222 PL        4     2     2 2020-11-01
#4   456 LO        2     1     1 2020-10-05
#5   678 IP        1     1     2 2020-11-02
```